# Datetime-local input doesn't accept the specified value

Tags: html, datetime, input, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have a datetime-local input.

I wish I had the ability to mandatory specify a date and optionally an hour.

Only, even when I indicate both, a warning occurs preventing me to get the input value.

Here is the warning message in question:

```
The specified value "0000-00-00T00:00" does not conform to the required format. The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".
```

I don't see where does the error or how to solve it.

Comment: how to solve this problem

Answer (score 7):

```
moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
```

Using moment.js it works with this format for type="datetime-local"

Answer (score 2):

The format is valid,
the date is invalid:
0th of month 0 of year 0 don't exists.

Comment: The specified value "2017-11-29T22:18:00.000Z" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Answer (score 1):

The datetime-local input accepts date value in the format: {date-value}T{time-value} and {time-value} shouldn't contain the UTC part.
So I suppose the problem is in your date value because "00" is not a valid value for day or month